# Flink Dead Lock at certain parallelism.

Tags: apache-flink

I run bfs written by myself in flink. And here is the code. But When    execution at certain parallelism. I have 16 machine(96 GB memory) and    20 task slot per taskmanager. And I set parallelism to 80. The    program will alwasy stuck at join step.

```
public class T2AdjMessage {

    private static final Integer STARTLEVEL = 1;

    private static Integer STARTPOINT = 2;

    private static String graphfile;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{

        ParameterTool params = ParameterTool.fromArgs(args);

        graphfile = params.get("file");

        STARTPOINT = params.getInt("start", 2);

        final int maxIterations = params.getInt("iterations", 20);

        // get environment
        final ExecutionEnvironment env = ExecutionEnvironment.getExecutionEnvironment();

        env.setParallelism(params.getInt("para",200));
```

> Graph reading

```
        //EdgeInput
        DataSet<Tuple2<Integer, Integer>> edgesInput = env.readTextFile(graphfile).map(
            new MapFunction<String, Tuple2<Integer, Integer>>() {
                @Override
                public Tuple2<Integer, Integer> map(String s) throws Exception {

                    String[] parts = s.split("\t");
                    if (parts.length != 2) {
                        throw new Exception("Input file error");
                    }

                    return new Tuple2<>(Integer.parseInt(parts[0].trim()), Integer.parseInt(parts[1].trim()));
                }
            }
        ).partitionByHash(0);


        DataSet<Tuple2<Integer, Iterable<Integer>>> adjlist = edgesInput.groupBy(0).reduceGroup(
            new GroupReduceFunction<Tuple2<Integer, Integer>, Tuple2<Integer, Iterable<Integer>>>() {
                @Override
                public void reduce(Iterable<Tuple2<Integer, Integer>> values, Collector<Tuple2<Integer, Iterable<Integer>>> out)
                    throws Exception {
                    ArrayList<Integer> al = new ArrayList<>();
                    int source = 0;
                    for(Tuple2<Integer,Integer> i : values){
                        al.add(i.f1);
                        source = i.f0;
                    }

                    out.collect(new Tuple2<Integer, Iterable<Integer>>(source, al));
                }
            }
        );


        //Vertex Input
        DataSet<Tuple2<Integer, Integer>> vertexWithLevel = adjlist.flatMap(
            new FlatMapFunction<Tuple2<Integer, Iterable<Integer>>, Tuple2<Integer, Integer>>() {
                @Override
                public void flatMap(Tuple2<Integer, Iterable<Integer>> value, Collector<Tuple2<Integer, Integer>> out)
                    throws Exception {
                    Integer u = value.f0;
                    out.collect(new Tuple2<Integer, Integer>(u, Integer.MAX_VALUE));
                    for (Integer i : value.f1){
                        out.collect(new Tuple2<Integer, Integer>(i, Integer.MAX_VALUE));
                    }
                }
            }
        ).groupBy(0).reduce(
            new ReduceFunction<Tuple2<Integer, Integer>>() {
                @Override
                public Tuple2<Integer, Integer> reduce(Tuple2<Integer, Integer> value1, Tuple2<Integer, Integer> value2)
                    throws Exception {
                    return value1.f1 < value2.f1 ? value1:value2;
                }
            }
        ).partitionByHash(0);

        DataSet<Tuple2<Integer, Integer>> pointInQ = env.fromElements(new Tuple2<Integer, Integer>(STARTPOINT,STARTLEVEL));
```

> Iteration Start

```
        final DeltaIteration< Tuple2<Integer, Integer>, Tuple2<Integer, Integer> > iterationDelta =
            vertexWithLevel.iterateDelta(pointInQ, maxIterations,0);

        setUpIteration(iterationDelta, env);
        DataSet<Tuple2<Integer,Integer>> activeV = iterationDelta.getSolutionSet().coGroup(iterationDelta.getWorkset())
            .where(0).equalTo(0).with(
            new CoGroupFunction<Tuple2<Integer, Integer>, Tuple2<Integer, Integer>, Tuple2<Integer, Integer>>() {
                @Override
                public void coGroup(Iterable<Tuple2<Integer, Integer>> first, Iterable<Tuple2<Integer, Integer>> second,
                                    Collector<Tuple2<Integer, Integer>> out) throws Exception {
                    Tuple2<Integer,Integer> x = first.iterator().next();
                    if(x != null){
                        int level = x.f1;
                        for (Tuple2<Integer, Integer> i : second){
                            if(level > i.f1){
                                level = i.f1;
                            }
                        }
                        if(level < x.f1){
                            out.collect(new Tuple2<Integer, Integer>(x.f0, level));
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        );
```

> //the program will stuck at join step

```
        // adjcent list join activeV produce message
        DataSet<Tuple2<Integer,Integer>> message = adjlist.join(activeV).where(0).equalTo(0).with(
            new RichFlatJoinFunction<Tuple2<Integer, Iterable<Integer>>, Tuple2<Integer, Integer>, Tuple2<Integer,
                Integer>>() {
                @Override
                public void join(Tuple2<Integer, Iterable<Integer>> first, Tuple2<Integer, Integer> second,
                                 Collector<Tuple2<Integer, Integer>> out) {
                    for (Integer x : first.f1) {
                        out.collect(new Tuple2<Integer, Integer>(x, second.f1 + 1));
                    }
                }
            }
        );

        DataSet<Tuple2<Integer, Integer>> finalVertexLevel = iterationDelta.closeWith(activeV, message);

        if (params.has("output")) {
            finalVertexLevel.writeAsCsv(params.get("output"), System.lineSeparator(), " ", OVERWRITE);
            env.execute("Join Edgeset");
        } else {
            System.out.println("Printing result to stdout. Use --output to specify output path.");

        }
    }

    private static void setUpIteration(DeltaIteration<?,?> iteration, ExecutionEnvironment env){
        iteration.parallelism(env.getParallelism());
        iteration.name("Join Edgeset");
    }
}
```

Comment: Does this even fails for some simple input file. How big is your input file? Do you maybe have a link to a github project so that we can run it by our own?

Comment: Twitter-2010 [data link](http://law.di.unimi.it/webdata/twitter-2010/)  This will not fail for simple input. This is [issue link](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/FLINK-8526) issue I submit for details.

Comment: Any update, were you able to resolve this issue? Your insights would be greatly appreciated